# Can the Google Console html verification file be used maliciously, when exposed?

Tags: google, search-engines

I was wondering, if the special html verification file can be used by "hackers". This file contains some unique string that is linked to a user's Google Console account.

Google asks the user **not to erase** it after the initial verification, or else the verification can be lost. Is it 100% safe to leave this file exposed?(let's say, in a public repository)?

Comment: I'd guess it's safe to make it public, because the same kind of verification can be done by adding that string as DNS record to your domain, and that DNS record would of course be public. Unless there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Yes..exactly..i was thinking the same about another method of verification: an html tag on the page itself. obviously it's totally exposed. But i'm "slightly" paranoid, so i want to make sure :D